# How can I set choice values in twig

Tags: html, symfony, twig

When I put this code I have an error.
Impossible to access an attribute ("value") on a string variable ("Etudiant").

CODE:

```
{{ form_widget(registrationForm.typePerso, 
   {'choices': {'Etudiant': 'Etudiant','Enseignant' : 'Enseignant'}})
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is from symfony Github:
"you cannot, because choices impact the building of the form. They are not passed as is to the template (they main goal of the Form component is not to handle the rendering, but to handle the form binding)"

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/18950